# java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to start receiver ET_GenericReceiver

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, mobilepush, mobilepush-android

In using the ExactTarget MobilePush Android SDK, you may get this exception showing up in LogCat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ET_GenericReceiver: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, can you add a little more information on what you're doing when this happens?

Comment: @LaceySnr I'm testing this platform for potential MobilePush team use.

Comment: Sorry all - these are FAQ for MobilePush product with ExactTarget Marketing Cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android SDK uses the app's label as the default when creating a notification inside ET_GenericReceiver.  Your ApplicationManifest.xml file needs to have a string resource defined for the label on the application tag.

```
<application ... android:label="@string/app_name" ...
```